# Not able to install bundle in felix console through maven

Tags: maven, aem, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am trying to install my bundle into **felix consol**e by using **maven**.

Here is the thing that I did differently is,

I created my own user (other than admin) and put that user in administrator group. Also I added my new user in **Apache Web Console Security Provider**. By this I am able to access and install bundle in `localhost:4502/system/console/bundles`. But if I try to use **maven** for same work than it gives following exception.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:install (install-content-package) on project testUser-content: Error while
 installing package. Check log for details. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:install (install-content-p
ackage) on project testUser-content: Error while installing package. Check log for details.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error while installing package. Check log for details.
        at com.day.jcr.vault.maven.mgr.PackageInstallMojo.uploadPackage(PackageInstallMojo.java:281)
        at com.day.jcr.vault.maven.mgr.PackageInstallMojo.execute(PackageInstallMojo.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: "Error while installing package. **Check log for details.**"
Did you follow this advice?

Comment: Yes but this is something related to user access so I didn't get much

Comment: Can you post the log here?

Comment: I already posted main part of log do you want me to put complete log file

Comment: Have you tried ro run maven with `-X` option to get some more debugging information?

Comment: Yes the above one is from there in normal mode it shows just build failed

Comment: Check the AEM error.log(s) for installation failure. If there are permission related issues they would be listed there. Make sure to increase your log level to INFO or DEBUG for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shared in the description indicates that the wrong maven plugin (`content-package-maven-plugin`) is invoked in order to install a `bundle` artifact.

A correct Maven plugin able to install `bundle` artifact is the [Maven Sling Plugin](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling.html) (`maven-sling-plugin`).

In order to use the `maven-sling-plugin` plugin, add the following in the build section of any `pom.xml` which produces `bundle` (the `packaging` tag of the artifact is `bundle`).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</plugin>
```

Then install the `bundle` by invoking the plugin as follow

```
$ mvn sling:install -Dsling.url=<host>:<port>/system/console
```

The `sling.url` and various other parameters can be configured once as part of your `pom.xml`. Please check the [complete plugin documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling.html).